# Get the number of affected rows in a MySQL update statement?

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure in MySQL, something like the below:

```
create procedure SP_Test (input1 varchar(20))
begin
update Table1 set Val1='Val' where country=input1;
//I want to see if this update changed how many rows and 
//do some specific action based on this number
....
end
```

How can I determine how many rows were changed by this update?

Answer (score 32):

Use [ROW_COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count):

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

Comment: Note this doesn't _appear_ (like a lot of other things) to work in _MySQL Workbench_ for Mac, but it does work in the console (and in stored procedures of course).

Comment: How to use it? Where to use it? It didn't answer the question. I'm getting row count = 0, when I know at least one was affected.

UPDATE Users SET Users.password=3 WHERE userID=1; //1 affected
SELECT ROW_COUNT(); // returns 0

Answer (score -2):

one way, not very optimal is to simply do a select before you do the update.

```
select count(*) from table1 where country = 'country1'
```

Comment: This will not tell how many rows have been changed by the `UPDATE`.

Comment: @dolmen it will IF the where clause matches the updates AND none of the fields in the where were set AND nothing else has changed them between update and select so definitely not ideal but feasible

Comment: That is a _mighty_big_ "if"

Answer (score -3):

Try the following code:

```
int mysql_affected_rows ([ resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

Comment: The question is about stored procedures.